# Getting Error in Pom.xml while running Twitter Websocket example?

Tags: twitter, websocket, apache-camel

getting error while running twitter websocket example from apache camel 2.10 error is ,

Description Resource Path Location Type
maven-remote-resources-plugin (goal "process") is ignored by m2e. pom.xml /camel-example-twitter-websocket line 26 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

while my Pom.xml file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.

-->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>examples</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>camel-example-twitter-websocket</artifactId>
  <name>Camel :: Example :: Twitter WebSocket</name>
  <description>An example that pushes new tweets to a web page using web-socket</description>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-twitter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging to the console -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Allows the example to be run via 'mvn compile exec:java' -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.apache.camel.example.websocket.CamelTwitterWebSocketMain</mainClass>
          <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-bundle-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.3.7,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>cleanVersions</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

Hopes for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its an error. Its most likely just Maven writing a WARN message or something.

Can you NOT run the example as documented?
http://camel.apache.org/twitter-websocket-example.html

Comment: Syed, its not very good to post the same question in many places and not tell about that. Also when you refer to some other resource, then provide the link. No other reads here at SO would be able to find "fuse ide forum".

Comment: Clause i will beware next time ...  well i run it and get this but unable to run localhost:9090 please check my this post

Comment: i also tried it first [root@localhost camel-example-twitter-websocket]# mvn compile
bash: mvn: command not found

Comment: and this one too [root@localhost camel-example-twitter-websocket]# mvn exec java
bash: mvn: command not found

Comment: If you want to run from command line, you need to install Apache Maven first - see here http://maven.apache.org/

Comment: if i do not want to run it from command line then ? and i am running it on fuse ide doesn't it have maven by default ?